# Why unrolling `while k() { f() }` to `f(); f()` results in a 25% performance drop, given the original loop always runs twice?

Tags: rust

I have a Rust program with the following shape:

```rust
  pub fn normal(&mut self, book: &Book) {
    self.expand(book, ROOT);
    while self.rdex.len() > 0 {
      self.reduce(book);
      self.expand(book, ROOT);
    }
  }
```

In a specific test, that loop is called exactly 2 times. So, I've updated it to:

```
  pub fn normal(&mut self, book: &Book) {
    self.expand(book, ROOT);
    self.reduce(book);
    self.expand(book, ROOT);
    self.reduce(book);
    self.expand(book, ROOT);
  }
```

I'm trying to understand which circumstances could led that to happen. I was wondering if perhaps the unrolled version was expanding the calls, resulting in register blowup, but using inline-never and inline-always didn't prevent the slowdown. What else could be causing it?

The relevant code is too big to be isolated. [Here](https://github.com/HigherOrderCO/hvm-core/blob/9810e9d83ae66cfa69154b0026b3bff15e59fd9b/src/run.rs#L792) it is. The issue can be replicated by uncommenting the marked lines and:

```
cargo install --path .
cd examples
hvmc run burn.hvmc
```

Comment: Can you please put the asm of the relevant function with both versions?

Comment: Also what are the absolute numbers? 25% of, say, 10 seconds is a noticeable difference. 25% of 1ms is noise in measurement.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev 25% of 1s runtime

Comment: @ChayimFriedman will do

Comment: If this is a test, and it's statically knowable that `self.rdex.len() == 2`, then the compiler can probably statically analyze the best way to handle this — maybe it can be smarter about it than just unrolling.

Comment: @BallpointBen there is no way to know that the loop will run only twice on this case as it depends on the dynamic input. I've unrolled just for this specific test because I was doing some refactors, and got surprised by the perf drop, so I asked with the intention of learning and understanding what's behind it

Comment: @ChayimFriedman

loop_normal.s: https://gist.github.com/Boscop/2e901d7ab87ba86655877a771160d13f --

unrolled_normal.s https://gist.github.com/Boscop/8b10d7584c148124f62561bb723ed8e3

Comment: It looks like the unroll has made the function too big, and that prevented inlining of functions inside it. That could be the reason for the slowdown.

Comment: I see, makes sense. So while the compiler can unroll if needed, it can not / will not usually convert two identical consecutive calls into a loop, right? Interesting

Comment: To test this hypothesis, try marking `interact()` and `reduce()` `#[inline(always)]`. I think `interact()` is the one not being inlined.

Comment: Sadly, using inline always on both doesn't improve performance. It seems like the compiler is still refusing to inline, I think / will check

Comment: We might be playing an inline game here: if we force the compiler to inline one function, it may end up not inlining another, previously inlined.

Comment: One thing you might want to look at is what PGO does to perf.